# VB.NET inheritance - do all properties in the derived classes have to be declared in the base class?

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns, inheritance

I'm refactoring, and have run into a roadblock.

**Background:**

I have a base class and several inherited derived classes.  The derived classes don't always need to have the same properties.  If any properties are shared among the derived classes, those properties would live at the base class level ('**Contents**', for example).

Similarly, GoodDocument below has '**GoodThings**' but would not want/need to have '**BadThings**'.

I want to treat instances of both '**GoodDocument**' and '**BadDocument**' as type '**Document**'

```
public mustinherit class Document
  public property Contents as string
  public sub new()...
end class 

public class GoodDocument
  inherits Document
  public property GoodThings as string
  public sub new()...
end class

public class BadDocument
  inherits Document
  public property BadThings as string
  public sub new()...
end class
```

The '**DocumentWriter**' class will also have several derived classes: ('**GoodDocumentWriter**' and '**BadDocumentWriter**').

I need to pass around the **DocumentWriter.Doc** as a 'Document' to a number of other places in the code.  *Doc.GoodThings would only be called from within an instance of either 'GoodDocument' or 'GoodDocumentWriter'.*

```
public mustinherit class DocumentWriter
  public property Doc as Document
  public sub new()... 
end class

public class GoodDocumentWriter
  inherits DocumentWriter
  public sub new 
    mybase.Doc = new GoodDocument
  end sub
end class

public class BadDocumentWriter
  inherits DocumentWriter
  public sub new 
    mybase.Doc = new BadDocument
  end sub
end class
```

**Question:**

- Is there a design pattern that allows for derived classes to have members that don't exist at the base class level?
- Do all properties have to live at the base class level?

**Revised**

I was trying to be brief with my initial question and I made the mistake of over simplifying the situation.  In short, I did realize that it should be possible to have different properties on each of the derived classes.  (I typed that in a tongue-in-cheek manor and didn't mean to keep it in the final post).

I realize now that the problem that I was experiencing was really symptomatic of a larger issue which needed addressing.

It appears that I was encountering compiler complaints that could be corrected by further refactoring and looser coupling.   While others answered the basic question that I posed, Ryan Gross' example really helped kick start some new ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should do in this case is define the operations that can be performed on instances of `Document` in an interface.  In your case maybe there is a WriteThings operation, so you would have:

```
public interface Writeable {
    public sub WriteThings();
}
```

Then in your derived classes you would implement the method to utilize the internal data of the class.  For example:

```
public mustinherit class Document implements Writeable
  public property Contents as string
  public sub new()...
  public sub WriteThings();
end class 

public class GoodDocument
  inherits Document
  public property GoodThings as string
  public sub new()...
  public sub WriteThings()
     //Do something with GoodThings
  end sub
end class

public class BadDocument
  inherits Document
  public property BadThings as string
  public sub WriteThings()
     //Do something with BadThings
  end sub
  public sub new()...
end class
```

Finally, client code that needs to call WriteThings accesses it through an interface:

```
public mustinherit class DocumentWriter
  public property Doc as Writable
  public sub new()... 
  public sub PerformWrite()
    Doc.WriteThings();
  end sub
end class
```

It is generally not a good idea to build several parallel class hierarchies.  In this case, one `DocumentWriter` class should be able to write any class that implements Writeable by invoking its WriteThings method.

Comment: I don't want to go nuts describing too much detail about actual code (unless it's helpful) but imagine that the DocumentWriter class had to (at the base class level) do something with one of the Document instances. 

Basically, the DocumentWriter class has code that doesn't need to change based on the Document type - it just needs to pass a ref to the specific Document instance to some other class.

What then?

Comment: I'm not sure why that would require a seperate DocumentWriter subclass for each Document type

Comment: In my project, there is a considerable amount of specific code that differs in each of the Document sub classes.  I've made those methods 'mustInherit' in the Document base class.  The problem that I can't sort out is when trying to deal with the Document instance outside of either of the derived classes.  There is a small amount of code that would be copy/pasted if it had to be removed from the DocumentWriter base class and put into each of the derived writer classes.  The only thing causing this would be the Document instance's type.  (passing ByRef doc as Document) doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I'm not sure that this is exactly what I'll end up with, but your example helped spark some fresh ideas.

Answer (score 1):

If all the properties live at the base class level, then I'm not sure what the point of a derived class would be. :) You'd be able to do everything with the base class.

So, yes. If something is applicable only to GoodDocument and not to Document, then it should be in GoodDocument.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question specifically:

- Yes, you just create multiple layers in the inheritance hierarchy: You have a base class, and then many two “branches” (good and bad, to use your terminology). Any properties that are only relevant to either branch, you declare in the class that inherits from the base class. Those properties will only be visible to that class and any classes inheriting from it.
- No, properties can be declared anywhere within your inheritance hierarchy.